# SD card LBA not starting with zero

Tags: micro-sd-card

I have a 16 GB SD card. I created two partitions on it to use it with my rooted phone, one FAT32 and one ext4 (possibly ext3 – I don't remember).

Now I've changed the SD card in my phone and I want to recreate the original state of this one. The problem is that I checked the SD card with MiniTool and EaseUS too, and the starting LBA is not zero – it is about ~ 2048. The size of the SD card now is 14.6.

- First physical sector 63
- Last physical sector 30844799
- Total physical sectors 30859264

My new 32 GB SD card for example has …

- First physical sector 0
- Last sector 61306879
- If I check the properties for the drive – not the partition – then the total physical sectors is 61306880

How can I fix it?